# Other Types of Order Types

Tags: set-theory

Consider following fundamental fact of ZFC.

**Fact**
‎‎$‎‎‎\forall ‎‎~\text{well-ordering}~\langle ‎A,<‎\rangle~~~‎\exists ‎!\alpha~~~‎‎‎‎‎\langle A,<‎‎\rangle‎\cong‎\langle‎\alpha‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎$‎

Each set ‎$‎‎\alpha$ ‎with ‎‎above ‎property is ‎called a ‎(Cantorian)‎ ‎"ordinal" ‎and ‎the ‎prope‎r class of all Cantorian ordinals is ‎$‎‎Ord$.‎
‎

In ‎the ‎philosophy of defining ‎‎ordinal ‎numbers ‎as "order types of well-orderings of the universe" ther‎e is a hidden notion of "uniformization" of well-ordering binary relations via a unique universal relation ‎$‎‎\in$ ‎on ‎‎whole $V‎$ ‎‎instead ‎of ‎using ‎different ordering relations like ‎‎$‎‎<$ ‎on ‎different ‎sets ‎$‎A‎$‎. Note that the complexity of each well-ordering ‎$\langle ‎A,<‎\rangle‎‎$ ‎depends ‎on "‎both" ‎underlying ‎set ‎‎$‎A‎$ ‎and ‎order ‎relation ‎‎$‎<‎$ ‎and ‎"both" ‎these ‎parameters ‎varies ‎over ‎different ‎well-orderings ‎but in order to define an ‎order ‎type class ‎like‎‎ $‎‎Ord$ ‎we ‎first "‎fix" a "‎uniform" ‎‎‎definable ‎binary ‎relation like ‎‎$‎‎\in$ ‎on ‎‎$‎‎V$ ‎an‎d then we find a class of special sets (Cantorian ordinals) which have all complexity of a well-ordering "just in their underlying set". In other words, as same as Mostovski collapsing theorem we send the complexity of the order ‎$‎‎<$ ‎to ordinal ‎$‎‎\alpha$ ‎and ‎so ‎it ‎suffices t‎o ‎change ‎th‎e "underlying set" of an ordinal to catch all different order types of the universe. ‎Now there is a natrural question here.
‎

**Main Question:** ‎
Is $‎‎\in$ ‎‎the "‎unique" ‎definable binary ‎relation ‎of ‎the ‎universe ‎which ‎can ‎serve ‎as a ‎order ‎type ‎defining ‎relation? ‎Is ‎‎$‎‎Ord$ ‎the ‎unique ‎class ‎of ‎order ‎types ‎in ‎the ‎universe?‎
‎

Let ‎us ‎make ‎our ‎main ‎question ‎precise.‎‎

**Definition:**
‎The definable binary relation ‎$‎‎E‎$ on ‎$‎V‎$‎ ‎has ‎the ‎**Order Type Property** ‎(OTP) ‎iff‎
$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\forall ‎‎~\text{well-ordering}~\langle ‎A,<‎\rangle~~~‎\exists ‎!a~~~‎‎‎‎‎\langle A,<‎‎\rangle‎\cong‎\langle a‎,E‎‎\rangle‎$‎ ‎

equivalently ‎

$‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\forall \alpha\in Ord‎‎~~~‎\exists ‎!a~~~‎‎‎‎‎\langle ‎\alpha‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎\cong‎\langle a‎,E‎‎\rangle‎‎‎$

For every ‎‎relation ‎‎$‎E‎$ ‎with ‎‎‎‎OTP, the proper class of ‎$‎E‎$‎-ordinals (‎‎$‎‎Ord_{E}$) ‎includes ‎all ‎"order type sets" ‎like ‎‎$‎a‎$‎. According to this definition it is clear that ‎$‎‎Ord_{\in}=Ord$‎.

**Remark:**  ‎‎
‎Note that there are many definable binary relations which doesn't have OTP. For some of them there is "no" order type set "‎‎$‎a‎$" ‎for ‎some (Cantorian) ‎ordinals ‎and ‎for ‎some ‎other relations ‎the‎re are "non-unique" order type sets for a particular (Cantorian) ordinal. For example consider:
‎‎

$$x ‎E_{1} y ‎\longleftrightarrow y\in x‎‎$$
  ‎‎

Note ‎that:‎
‎

$$ \exists‎ \alpha\in Ord‎‎~~\forall a~~\langle ‎\alpha‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎\ncong‎\langle a‎,E‎‎\rangle $$

Just consider ‎$‎‎‎\alpha ‎=\omega‎$ and note that the order type set ‎$‎‎a$ should be non-well founded because ‎if $f:‎‎‎‎‎‎\langle ‎\omega‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎\longrightarrow‎ ‎‎‎‎\langle a‎,E‎‎\rangle$ ‎is an isomorphism then we have ‎$‎‎f(0)‎\ni f(1)\ni f(2)\ni \cdots‎$‎ ‎a contradiction to well-foundedness of ‎$‎a‎$‎.‎
‎

As another example define ‎$‎‎E_{2}$ ‎as ‎follows:‎

‎‎$$ xE_{2}y‎‎\longleftrightarrow ‎\cup x\in \cup y‎‎‎‎ $$

Note that: ‎
‎‎

$$ (1)~\forall \alpha\in Ord~~‎‎~‎\exists a~~~‎‎‎‎‎\langle ‎\alpha‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎\cong‎\langle a‎,E‎‎\rangle‎‎ $$

But ‎the ‎uniqueness ‎fails. ‎i.e.,‎

‎$$ (2)~‎\exists‎ \alpha\in Ord~~‎‎\exists a_1, a_2~‎‎‎‎‎a_1\neq a_2~‎\wedge‎~‎\langle a_1‎,E‎‎\rangle\cong\langle ‎\alpha‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎\cong‎\langle a_2‎,E‎‎\rangle‎‎ $$‎‎

‎To see ‎$‎‎(1)$ ‎note ‎that ‎we ‎have ‎‎$‎‎\forall \alpha\in Ord~~~‎‎‎‎‎\langle ‎\alpha‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎\cong‎\langle \alpha^{\star}‎,E‎‎\rangle‎$‎ ‎when ‎‎$‎‎‎\alpha‎^{\star}:=\{\{\beta\}~|~\beta\in \alpha\}$‎.‎

To see ‎$‎‎(2)$ ‎consider ‎$‎‎\alpha=‎\omega‎$ ‎and ‎‎define $‎\omega‎^{\star}:=\{\{0\}, \{1\}, \{2\},\cdots \}‎$‎ ‎and ‎‎$‎‎‎\omega‎^{\star\star}:=\{1, 2, 3,\cdots \}$ ‎then ‎we ‎have ‎$\omega^{\star}\neq \omega^{\star\star}‎$ ‎and ‎$‎‎\langle ‎\omega‎,\in‎‎\rangle \cong ‎\langle \omega^{\star}‎,E‎‎\rangle$ ‎by map ‎$‎‎n‎\mapsto ‎\{n\}‎$ ‎and ‎‎$\langle ‎\omega‎,\in‎‎\rangle‎‎‎\cong‎\langle \omega^{\star\star}‎,E‎‎\rangle‎$ ‎by map ‎$‎‎n‎\mapsto ‎n+1‎$‎ ‎‎as ‎required.‎‎

Now ‎the ‎precise ‎form ‎of ‎our ‎main ‎question ‎is as follows:‎‎
‎

‎**Is ‎$‎‎\in$ the only definable binary relation on ‎$‎V‎$ ‎with Order Type Property?‎‎‎**

Comment: You really need to fix your MathJax codes. The `$` seem to have messed up somewhere around the question.

Comment: Your statement is utterly false. $(\{x\},\in)$ is always a set well-ordered by $\in$. But unless $x=\varnothing$, this is not an ordinal. The uniqueness comes from the additional requirement of transitivity.